# How can I obtain a reference to the URL that was used to open my app with a link in iOS

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a problem with the situation where my React Native Expo app is running in the background / inactive modus and the app is brought back to the foreground / active mode as a result of the user opening a deep link to my app from the mobile browser.

When this situation occurs, my app needs to get a reference to the deep link in order to show the expected content to the user. The problem is that `Linking.getInitialURL()` always returns the link that was used to open the app from cold start and not the link that was used to bring the app back to foreground / active modus.

Advice on how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found it out by myself :-)

```
    useEffect(() => {
        Linking.addEventListener('url', handleLinkEvent);

        return () => {
            Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleLinkEvent);
        };
    }, []);
```

For these cases you should use `Linking.addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

To complete @timboektoe's answer, react-navigation offers a subscribe function to listen to any URL received.

```js
const subscribe = (listener) => {
  const onReceiveURL = ({ url }) => { listener(url); };
  const subscription = Linking.addEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);
    
  return () => {
    subscription.remove();
  };
};
    
const linking = {
  prefixes,
  config,
  getInitialURL,
  subscribe,
};
```